# Mailchimp: Get Interest ID with Interest Name?

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I know that when you do a call like this:

lists/{list id}/interest-categories/{interest category id}/interests/

You can get all the Interests and loop through them to get the ID you want. But, I have thousands of interests, which makes for an insane loop search.

Is there a way to get the interest ID for one particular interest? I know you can get a user just by hashing their email, so can the same be done using the Interest Name?

I just want the one Interest ID.

Cheers!
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
lists/{list_id}/interest-categories/{interest_category_id}/interests/{id}
```